# Read optimizations on shared memory

Tags: c, gcc, concurrency

Suppose you have a function that make several read access to a shared variable whose access is atomic. All in running in the same process. Imagine them as threads of a process or as a sw running on bare metal platform with no MMU.

As a requirement you must ensure that the value of that read is consistent for all the length of the function so the code must not re-read the memory location and have to put in a local variable or on a register. How can we ensure that this behaviour is respected?

As an example...

> shared is the only shared variable

```
extern uint32_t a, b, shared;

void useless_function()
{
  __ASM volatile ("":::"memory");
  uint32_t value = shared;
  a = value *2;
  b = value << 3;
}
```

Can value be optimized out by direct readings of shared variable in some contexts? If yes, how can I be sure this cannot happen?

Comment: On a preemptive multitasking system there's no way to guarantee that the value of `shared` (which I assume is your "shared variable") will stay consistent across the function.

Comment: Why aren't the shared variables marked as volatile?

Comment: Maybe I'm not been clear really, I don't mind if shared changes. What I need is that shared is read only once and it local value keeped for all function length and not re-evaluated, so something just opposite of volatile.

Comment: Isn't that what the variable `value` is for?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude yep, but my fear is that variable can be optimized by direct reads to shared in some contexes.

Comment: Then make *that* variable `volatile`, so access to it won't be optimized?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude you mean the local variable value?  I'm not so confident of what can happen in this case. Can you explain it better?

Comment: If the variable is stored in shared memory, you will only have a pointer to the variable (unless you play some funny assembly language tricks and locate the process's stack into shared memory — but you can't do that with global variables).  To ensure consistency, you will need to use a locking mechanism — an inter-process mutex, or a semaphore, or something similar — in every process that accesses the variable in shared memory.  How many such locks you have depends on how big your shared memory segments are, and how many variables you need to protect, and so on.

Comment: Sorry, I've been not clear on this, I'm on bare metal, no virtual memory, only static allocation whose access are shared bitween tasks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As a requirement you must ensure that the value of that read is consistent for all the length of the function so the code must not re-read the memory location and have to put in a local variable or on a register. How can we ensure that this behaviour is respected?

You can do that with [`READ_ONCE` macro from Linux kernel](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.4.8/source/include/linux/compiler.h#L238):

```
/*
 * Prevent the compiler from merging or refetching reads or writes. The
 * compiler is also forbidden from reordering successive instances of
 * READ_ONCE and WRITE_ONCE, but only when the compiler is aware of some
 * particular ordering. One way to make the compiler aware of ordering is to
 * put the two invocations of READ_ONCE or WRITE_ONCE in different C
 * statements.
 *
 * These two macros will also work on aggregate data types like structs or
 * unions. If the size of the accessed data type exceeds the word size of
 * the machine (e.g., 32 bits or 64 bits) READ_ONCE() and WRITE_ONCE() will
 * fall back to memcpy(). There's at least two memcpy()s: one for the
 * __builtin_memcpy() and then one for the macro doing the copy of variable
 * - '__u' allocated on the stack.
 *
 * Their two major use cases are: (1) Mediating communication between
 * process-level code and irq/NMI handlers, all running on the same CPU,
 * and (2) Ensuring that the compiler does not fold, spindle, or otherwise
 * mutilate accesses that either do not require ordering or that interact
 * with an explicit memory barrier or atomic instruction that provides the
 * required ordering.
 */
```

E.g.:

```
uint32_t value = READ_ONCE(shared);
```

`READ_ONCE` macro essentially casts the object you read to be `volatile` because the compiler cannot emit extra reads or writes for `volatile` objects.

The above is equivalent to:

```
uint32_t value = *(uint32_t volatile*)&shared;
```

Alternatively:

```
uint32_t value;
memcpy(&value, &shared, sizeof value);
```

`memcpy` breaks the dependency between `shared` and `value`, so that the compiler cannot re-load `shared` instead of loading `value`.

Comment: Is that behaviour compiler dependent or is standard defined? Never heard of it. Anyways I'm givin it a quick test

Comment: @Damiano Both methods (casting to `volatile` and `memcpy`) are required to not produce extra loads by the standard. I don't have access to C standard to quote it, though.

Comment: From the link you quoted, it seems that memcpy is used only if you want to handle types bigger than a word.

Comment: @Damiano `memcpy` can be used for any trivial type. For built-in integer types `memcpy` compiles into plain `mov`, just like with that cast to `volatile`. See https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/6rUDhD

Comment: I suspected that but never checked it out, think it depends on linker optimization flags. Nice website, I didn't know it, thanks :)

Comment: @Damiano That is a compiler optimization, `memcpy` is a compiler intrinsic function, unless you disable intrinsic functions with `-fno-builtin` (the kernel build may do that, but I haven't checked).

Answer (score 0):

In the example given you are not using the variable `value` in the function at all. So it will definitely be optimised.

Also, as mentioned in comments, in a multitasking system, the value of `shared` can be changed within the function.

> What I need is that shared is read only once and it local value keeped for all function length and not re-evaluated

I would suggest something like this below.

```
extern uint32_t a, b, shared;

void useless_function()
{
  __ASM volatile ("":::"memory");
  uint32_t value = shared;
  a = value*2;
  b = value << 3;
}
```

Here `shared` is read only once in the function. It will be read again on next call of the function.

Comment: You are right. That was an error.... are you sure that "value" cannot be optimized and changed by direct read to shared by the compiler?

Comment: IMO the compiler should not read the `shared` variable multiple times. If you are concerned about this you can set it as `volatile`